# While running and login meteor application ddp-server throwing Exception

Tags: meteor

My application is build and run but while login I am getting exception 
Exception while invoking method 'login' Error: setUserId must be called on string or null, not object

I am new to meteor and do not have idea about it please help.

I was trying to debug my code using debugger in ddp.server as well ddp.common but get no luck.

```
  Meteor.loginWithLdap(username, password, function(err){
      if (err) {
        Toast.error(err.message, 'Login Failed');
        $('#isforms-password').val("");
      }
    });
```

In this coded snippet I am getting error.

Just need suggestion tat what is going north in my project.

Comment: Any error outputs on the server console?

Comment: Need more information, like are you using some package? Is there other code involved?